# Android: cannot play mp4 video

Tags: android, streaming, mp4, android-videoview

I'm trying to play **mp4 videos streaming** from a server using native **VideoView**, sadly I keep getting a "**Cannot play video**" error.

The weird thing is that the same video plays well on Froyo but will not play on HoneyComb. 
I tried the same video with MX Video Player (on HC) and it plays just fine.

Another major problem is that I cannot re-encode the videos, so I have to use the videos as they are.

- What is causing the error?
- How can I play the video?
- Should I find a way to include a codec library into my app?

Below are details from logcat:

```
E/MediaExtractor(  242): **********MediaExtractor::Create
D/DivXPlugin(  241): DivXPlugin::onInitialize : 75
D/DivXPlugin(  241): DivXPlugin::onSetOnInfoListener : 75
D/DivXPlugin(  241): DivXPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession: Enter : 75
E/DivXPlugin(  241): DivXPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession() Not a Divx File.
E/DrmManager(Native)(  241): DrmManager::openDecryptSession: no capable plug-in found
D/DivXPlugin(  241): DivXPlugin::onTerminate : 75
E/MediaExtractor(  242): ************Autodetected media content as 'video/mpeg4' with confidence 0.40
D/AwesomePlayer(  242): finishSetDataSource_l getDrmInfo
D/AwesomePlayer(  242): setDataSource_l
E/MPEG4Extractor(  242): ftyp chunk found
D/MPEG4Extractor(  242): kKeyAVCC found
E/MPEG4Extractor(  242): ERROR_MALFORMED because ret=-108
E/MPEG4Extractor(  242): return ERROR_UNSUPPORTED
E/MPEG4Extractor(  242): return ERROR_UNSUPPORTED
D/AwesomePlayer(  242): UNKNOWN_ERROR: no Video and no Audio
D/AwesomePlayer(  242): abortPrepare
D/AwesomePlayer(  242): notifyListener_l
E/MediaPlayer( 3906): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer( 3906): Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView( 3906): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

And the specs of the video that cannot be played:

```
    General
    Format                           : MPEG-4
    Format profile                   : Base Media
    Codec ID                         : isom
    File size                        : 60.7 MiB
    Duration                         : 7mn 3s
    Overall bit rate mode            : Variable
    Overall bit rate                 : 1 201 Kbps
    Writing application              : Lavf52.37.0

    Video
    ID                               : 1
    Format                           : AVC
    Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
    Format profile                   : High@L3.1
    Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
    Format settings, ReFrames        : 4 frames
    Codec ID                         : avc1
    Codec ID/Info                    : Advanced Video Coding
    Duration                         : 7mn 3s
    Duration_FirstFrame              : 40ms
    Bit rate                         : 1 072 Kbps
    Width                            : 1 024 pixels
    Height                           : 576 pixels
    Display aspect ratio             : 16:9
    Frame rate mode                  : Constant
    Frame rate                       : 25.000 fps
    Color space                      : YUV
    Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
    Bit depth                        : 8 bits
    Scan type                        : Progressive
    Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.073
    Stream size                      : 54.2 MiB (89%)
    Writing library                  : x264 core 65 r0+1016 dbc5ef0
    Encoding settings                : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy_rd=1.0:0.0 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / mbaff=0 / bframes=16 / b_pyramid=0 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / wpredb=1 / keyint=125 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40(pre) / rc=2pass / bitrate=1072 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.80 / qpmin=10 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ip_ratio=1.41 / pb_ratio=1.25 / aq=1:1.00
    Language                         : English

    Audio
    ID                               : 2
    Format                           : AAC
    Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec
    Format profile                   : LC
    Codec ID                         : 40
    Duration                         : 7mn 3s
    Bit rate mode                    : Variable
    Bit rate                         : 122 Kbps
    Channel(s)                       : 2 channels
    Channel positions                : Front: L R
    Sampling rate                    : 48.0 KHz
    Compression mode                 : Lossy
    Stream size                      : 6.18 MiB (10%)
    Language                         : English
```

Comment: I was thinking of adding ffmpeg library to my app, but I know little about android NDK. Anyone has hints or link to provide?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with the video encoding. Android FROYO and Gingerbread doesn't support H264 formats other than **"Baseline" H264.** So if your video is Mp4 & H264 encoded make sure its  "AVC baseline" encoded. Use some tools like "Media info" in windows/Linux and check your video encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Some Froyo devices (e.g., Samsung Galaxy Tab) use the OpenCore mediaframework while others use Stagefright. From gingerbread all devices to my knowledge use Stagefright. So this could maybe explain your experience.

When playing over HTTP or RSTP there are additional constraints for the video container.

from the developer docs:

> For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat
>   atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom.