# Android how to play video using video URL?

Tags: android

I have Url like http://www.logisticinfotech.com/client/Malasiya%20Cup/movie.mp4 i want play this video in my video player in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a VideoView just set the uri: `videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));`

Comment: 01-03 20:11:49.224: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('www.logisticinfotech.com/client/Malasiya Cup/movie.mp4')
01-03 20:11:49.244: ERROR/MediaPlayer(420): error (1, -2147483648)
01-03 20:11:49.284: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.logistic.videoview/.MainActivity: 855 ms (total 855 ms)
01-03 20:11:49.354: ERROR/MediaPlayer(420): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-03 20:11:49.354: DEBUG/VideoView(420): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: i got the same problem ([http://stackoverflow.com/q/8602385/935075](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8602385/935075)), never figured it out, sorry. You can always re-encode your video.

Answer (score 0):

The stock video player does not support playing from URLs. Install third party software like [doubleTwist](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer&hl=en) or [MX Video Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en).

Comment: ..I just play it in android video player ,just like click on video(in sdcard) and  play in android.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. In that case, use the code sebataz has given. Also, NOTE that the Android Emulator does NOT play any Videos. You've to install it in the device to test the video playing.