# Open Stream camera from URL

Tags: android, video, stream

I have static html with this code:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <img width='100%' height='100%' src='http:/ip:port//urlMyCam'>
 </body>
</html>
```

That HTML works fine when I use it on my computer with my so I can watch my cam in real time perfectly.

But now I am trying open this stream in android its not work.

Already tried this way (nothing happens):

```
webViewCamera.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webViewCamera.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<html><head></head><body><img  src='" + urldisplay + "'></body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

and this way with a videoView (Sorry, this video cannot be played ):

```
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoViewCamera);
            videoViewCamera.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoViewCamera.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urldisplay.toString()));
            videoViewCamera.requestFocus();
            videoViewCamera.start();
```

Maybe another way? What am I doing wrong?

(EDITED)
i got this error on LogCat

```
03-23 14:34:36.830: E/GenericSource(1831): [multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--DigifortBoundary; charset=ISO-8859-1]
03-23 14:34:39.115: E/DivXPlugin(1830): DivXPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession() Not a Divx File.
03-23 14:34:39.115: E/SEC_DRM_PLUGIN_Playready(1830):  PlayreadyPlugIn::onOpenDecryptSession()   DRM_ASFVerify_Context_Initialize is failed
03-23 14:34:39.120: E/GenericSource(1831): initFromDataSource() mExtractor is NULL, mFlags is PREPARE_CANCELLED
03-23 14:34:39.120: E/MediaPlayer(9006): error (1, -1004)
03-23 14:34:39.120: E/MediaPlayer(9006): Error (1,-1004)
```

Comment: Some extra information would be nice. Is the Android phone an emulator on your PC? Did you set the settings correctly so this port can be watched from outside of your network? What format does the IP cam use to display the feed.

Comment: is my tablet samsung galaxy tab3 lite, the url and port is correclty i can acess with my html in my computer (is not the same of the url)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602385/android-cannot-play-mp4-video

Comment: yes, i think is it, because in my nexus its works fine (with webview), but i dont know how i can solve it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i leave it out this solution and use another app to open my stream, download RTSP Player and always use this app to open my url.

[RTSP Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rtspplr.app&hl=en)

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse(urldisplay.toString()), "video/*"));
```